# How to delete a kubernetes cluster created by AKS engine?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have created a kubernetes cluster using `aks-engine deploy` command on azure. Now I want to delete the whole cluster with associated nodes. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

just delete the resource group using any means, like Azure portal, or Azure Cli\Powershell.

Comment: what if the resource group has other resources?

Comment: well, the only other options is to delete those resources manually\with a script one by one, but aks engine (by default) would create a new resource group, hence my answer